# vb.net split every second same character

Tags: replace, split, format

Regards to all.
I try to find simple solutions for this. Outpot from my class Mikrotik API is:

```
uptime=14w3d8h50m4s=version=6.30.4=build-time=Aug/25/2015 12:59:46=free-memory=67649536=total-memory=134217728=cpu=MIPS 24Kc V7.4=cpu-count=1=cpu-frequency=680=cpu-load=50=free-hdd-space=114511872=total-hdd-space=134217728=write-sect-since-reboot=159485=write-sect-total=657518=bad-blocks=0=architecture-name=mipsbe=board-name=RB433GL=platform=MikroTik
```

What we need is format strings like that:

```
uptime: 14w3d8h50m46s
version: 6.30.4
build-time: Aug/25/2015 12:59:46
free-memory: 64.6MiB
total-memory: 128.0MiB
cpu: MIPS 24Kc V7.4
cpu-count: 1
cpu-frequency: 680MHz
cpu-load: 36%
free-hdd-space: 109.2MiB
total-hdd-space: 128.0MiB
write-sect-since-reboot: 159487
write-sect-total: 657520
bad-blocks: 0%
architecture-name: mipsbe
board-name: RB433GL
platform: MikroTik
```

A good solution would be to split text on every two (second) character `=` or replace with `vbCrLf` for result:

```
uptime=14w3d8h50m46s
version=6.30.4
build-time=Aug/25/2015 12:59:46
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution:

```
Dim input As String = "uptime=1w12h14m47s=version=6.30.4=build-time=Aug/25/2015 12:59:46"
Dim words As String() = input.Split(New Char() {"="c})
Dim result As String = String.Empty
Dim count As Integer = 1
For Each word In words
    If count = 1 Then
       count = 0
       result += word + ": "
    Else
       result += word + vbCrLf
              count += 1
    End If
Next
MsgBox(result)
```

Result is:

```
uptime: 14w3d8h50m46s
version: 6.30.4
build-time: Aug/25/2015 12:59:46
```